# Optimization of multiple functions

Tags: python, optimization

I have 3 functions which consist of 6 variables (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6). The value of each function is equal to x (say):

```
f1= 
sgn(2-p1)*sqrt(abs(2-p1))+sgn(2-p2)*sqrt(abs(2-p2))+sgn(2-p3)*sqrt(abs(2-p3));

f2= sgn(p4-2)*sqrt(abs(p4-2))+sgn(p5-2)*sqrt(abs(p5-2))+sgn(p6-2)*sqrt(abs(p6-2));

f3= 
sgn(p1-p4)*sqrt(abs(p1-p4))+sgn(p2-p5)*sqrt(abs(p2-p5))+sgn(p3-p6)*sqrt(abs(p3-p6));
```

I want to find the combination of values of p1,p2,p3,p4,p5 and p6 for which x is maximum. Constraints are:
0 <= p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6 <= 4

Simply varying every variable from 0 to 4 taking small steps is not a good solution. Can someone tell me an efficient method to optimise the solution (preferably in python).

Comment: possibly better suited community for this question over at  https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-linear optimization problem without an obvious close form solution. Better ask this question in another forum.